# Character issue UTF-8 LAMP CentOS

Tags: php, linux, apache, centos, lamp

After installing LAMP on CentOS, everything works fine but show a problem with  characters, every letters such as `"í" "ú" "ò"` and other classic characters are replaced by `"?"`, frequently recurring problem with `UTF-8.`

So I've change settings as:

```
**http.conf** : AddDefaultCharset utf-8


in **php.ini** : default_charset = "utf-8"
mbstring.internal_encoding=utf-8
mbstring.http_output=UTF-8
mbstring.encoding_translation=On
mbstring.func_overload=6

**my.conf**   character_set_server=utf8    

**in html php file**: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

and finally on  /etc/sysconfig/i18n with this code :

default setting:

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
SYSFONT="latarcyrheb-sun16"
```

my setting:

```
LANG="it_IT.UTF-8"
SYSFONT="latarcyrheb-sun16"
```

italian is my language , after this  also show the command linux `""locale ""`

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

if you show not change the language , why ??

Comment: Where are you having this problem exactly? The console? A browser accessing sites hosted on that machine? Somewhere else?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue? I am facing same with Java application